# Formatting Excel-Formula

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have made an excel formula that will take the data entered into column O and then multiply it by .04 and then input that data into column P. So I can calculate a four percent fee from the original number. I am now left with a bunch of $0.00 in every row in the P column that lacks data in the O column.  I understand this is because 0*.04 = 0. But what I was wondering is if there was a way to make it so that if the total in column P was less than $0.01 or equivalent to $0.00 that the cell would remain blank.

I tried to post an image to show exactly what I am talking about, but I do not yet have the reputation. Hopefully you can understand what I am trying to do based off what I typed.

Answer (score 1):

Do conditional formatting of the cell such that if the value = 0, the number type is "general"

Then, in your formula for the cell itself (assuming you multiply C3*B3), you can do this:

```
=IF(C3*B3>0,C3*B3,"")
```

This will use number formatting for all values that are non-zero, but empty string `""` with general formatting for zero values.

Answer (score 1):

Method 1:

Select the cells with the percentages in column P and tap <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>1</kbd>. When the **Format Cells** dialog opens, go to the **Number** tab and choose **Custom** from the list down the left. Supply the following in the *Type:* textbox.

```
$#,##0.00;;;
```

Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the lower right.

Method 2:

Go into **Excel Options** (<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F</kbd>,<kbd>T</kbd>) and choose **Advanced** from the list down the left. Scroll the right pane down to the **Display options for this worksheet** section and uncheck *Show a zero in cells that have a zero value*. Click <kbd>OK</kbd> in the lower right.

Answer (score 0):

You can use conditional formatting when the value is less than 0.01 make the font white

The cell will still be 0 but not visible

Answer (score 0):

Try this: `=IF(O2<0.01,"",O2*0.04)`. This particular formula is checking to see if cell O2 is less than 0.01, and if so is filling in the P2 cell with a zero-length string. If O2 is equal or larger than 0.01 it will multiply by .04 and put that result in cell P2.